# What is the proper way to spell and pronounce the name Yoanna or some certain names?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, names, cultural-correctness

My name is "Yoanna" but I am not sure of how to pronounce or spell it properly in English. It is derived from "Joanna". Should I write it "Joanna" and pronounce it "Yoanna" or do I stick with "Yoanna" in either cases?

Also, using the example above, is it okay if I write English names that are pronounced differently in other countries the same way they are pronounced or do I just write them like their English form and pronounce them differently based on culture and language?

Comment: This is purely a matter of choice, though perhaps tempered somewhat by the pragmatics of having others pronounce your name.  (And there's nothing wrong with "Yoanna" -- it's not terribly strange and I think most English speakers would pronounce it reasonably well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question!

It looks like the proper spelling is *Yoanna*. If you want to Anglicize it, then yes, use *Joanna*. It's your choice.

But use just one spelling and pronunciation, not two. That would confuse people. Either make it Yoanna or Joanna all the time, both written and spoken.

Comment: I really want to know if there is a chance that name is common among English Speakers because I remain very skeptical about that name. Thank you a lot for your time.

Comment: I've never heard it before, but as it's your name. you have a right to expect English speakers to use it, especially as it's not difficult for an English speaker to say. (When I spent a year in Switzerland as a student, I had to let most people call me Katherine, with the French pronunciation, because French speakers couldn't say _Kate_!)